# Драйвер переключения раскладки клавиатуры на Delphi

Tags: delphi

Пытаюсь сочинить код для переключения раскладки клавиатуры клавишей Caps-Lock. Нахожу это наиболее удобным переключать раскладку мизинцем левой руки вместо громоздких комбинаций с Ctrl и Alt, которые сбивают ритм набора (вот и сейчас именно так). Что-то рабочее получилось, но проблема в том, что кнопка Caps-Lock отрабатывается системой и хотя код переключает ее обратно, но эти миллисекунды при быстром наборе сильно мешают и тормозят набор текста. Кроме того я не программист поэтому не судите строго, не пойму как сделать код глобальным. Вот сам код:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var Layout: array[0.. KL_NAMELENGTH] of char;
begin
  if GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)<>0 then
  begin
      GetKeyboardLayoutName(Layout);
          if Layout = '00000419' then LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409', 1)
             else
             if Layout = '00000409' then LoadKeyboardLayout('00000419', 1);

    Keybd_Event(VK_CAPITAL, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or 0, 0);
    //Keybd_Event(VK_CAPITAL, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    //keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, 1, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, 1, vk_up, 0);
    timer1.Enabled:=false;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) = 0 then timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;
```

Comment: Переключение раскладки при помощи CapsLock можно включить в настройках операционной системы. Без обид, Просто это гораздо быстрее, чем строить свой велосипед с квадратными колёсами.

Comment: На виндовс 7 нет.

Comment: Можно настроить переключение [через реестр](http://playground.teerapap.net/2008/03/switch-input-language-by-caps-lock.html) или взять одну из [готовых утилит](http://dae.me/blog/1173/pereklyucheniye-yazika-vvoda-po-caps-lock-v-windows/). Как минимум одна из тех утилит, идёт с сорцами (на Си): [lswitch](http://haali.su/winutils/) - можно изучить и перевести на Delphi.

Comment: Благодарю. Через реестр работает.